# AuthorizationError when publishing sns message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-sns

**Summary**
A user is unable to publish to sns even after all permissions have been granted.

**Description:**
Using cloudformation, i created an SNS topic and SNS topic policy

```
 TopicNameSNS:
   Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
   Properties:
     KmsMasterKeyId: 'alias/aws/sns'
     TopicName: TopicNameSNS
TopicNameSNSTopicPolicy:
   Type: 'AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy'
   Properties:
     Topics:
       - {Ref: TopicNameSNS}
     PolicyDocument:
       Version: '2012-10-17'
       Statement:
         - Sid: 'Allow publishing to the topic'
           Action:
             - sns:Publish
           Effect: Allow
           Resource: {Ref: TopicNameSNS}
           Principal:
             AWS:
               - 'arn:aws:iam::<account_1_id>:user/<account_1_user_name>'
```

This cloudformation template is used to create these resources in `account_2`

On my terminal using the credentials for `account_1` i am trying to publish a message to the sns topic but i keep getting an authorization error.

Command:

```
aws sns publish \
    --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account_2>:TopicNameSNS" \
    --message file://sns_message.txt
```

result:

```
An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the Publish operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<account_1>:user/<account_1_user_name> 
is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account_2>:TopicNameSNS
```

Looks like the topic policy just doesn't work. I also added a new policy to  user

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account_2>:TopicNameSNS"
        }
    ]
}
```

But i still get the same error.

**Question:**

How do i enable a user to publish messages to an sns topic? I would prefer using the topic policy but i can also modify the iam user policy if the topic policy is impossible.

Comment: What are these: `<account_2>` or `{Ref: TopicNameSNS}` Just a placeholders for SO or you actually have such stuff in your code?

Comment: Placeholders for SO

Comment: In this case I think the principle for the `account_1` should be root, `arn:aws:iam::<account_1_id>:root`.

Comment: Doesn't that grant the root user access to publish? I want to Grant a specific IAM user publish access.

Comment: Yes, you grant access to other account. The root of other account grants to its IAM user. You should be able to limit which specific IAM user can publish using `aws:PrincipalArn` in sns policy condition.

Comment: Looks like i still need to give the iam user permission to publish to that topic.